# Laravel Abort and Exceptions adding debug/stack trace to API response | APP_DEBUG=FALSE

Tags: exception, laravel-5, throw, abort

If I throw an exception in my API controllers/routes it always returns an object including the stack trace. I have set APP_DEBUG=FALSE and APP_ENV=production yet I always get a stack trace like below...

Say I throw any one of these in a controllers method:

```
throw new HttpException(410, 'Http Exception is getting a stack trace.');

abort(404, 'Please tell me debug is not found!');

throw new UpdateResourceFailedException('Even my custom exception! How?', 422);
```

It returns an object like this:

```
{
    "message": "Message",
    "status_code": 410,
    "debug": {
        "line": 412,
        "file": "/var/www/example.com/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
        "trace": [
            "#0 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\OrderController->show()",
            "#1 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array()",
            "#2 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()",
            "#3 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()",
            "#4 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()",
            "#5 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()",
            "#6 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()",
            "#7 /var/www/example.com/vendor/dingo/api/src/Http/Middleware/Auth.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()",
            "#8 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Dingo\\Api\\Http\\Middleware\\Auth->handle()",
            "#9 /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"...
```

I can't turn it off or figure out why it's adding it. Any help would be appreciated. Yes, I have dumped my .env variables and my config file to see what the system thinks the value is and invariably it's:
`"debug":false`

Any ideas on why this is returning debug?

Comment: ***FOUND THE ISSUE*** 
Problem 1 - WE USE DINGO FOR OUR API
Problem 2 - DINGO has a setting for the API's response that needs to be set to API_DEBUG=FALSE (this was in our .env - you might need to look at a config file though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always catch these errors and return exception messages as responses.

```
try{
    //throw exception here
     throw new UpdateResourceFailedException('Even my custom exception! How?', 422);
 }catch(UpdateResourceFailedException $ex){
   // when you want http response
   // return response(['custom_exception'=>$ex->getMessage()], 4xx); 
   // when you want resposne as json
     return response()->json(['custom_exception'=>$ex->getMessage()], 4xx); 
 }
```

You can return these exceptions along with status codes.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/throwable.getmessage.php

Comment: Yes, while it doesn't help me solve the problem, this is what I've decided to do. I wish I could understand what's causing this as it would be really nice to use laravel's exceptions and abort method instead of using `return response()->json()` but after a whole day wasted trying to dig through code to understand the problem, sometimes it's better to just accept a different solution. I'll make a facade and wrap this up so it's a little nicer to call and requires a message and maybe a code.

Comment: ***FOUND THE ISSUE*** 
Problem 1 - WE USE DINGO FOR OUR API
Problem 2 - DINGO has a setting for the API's response that needs to be set to API_DEBUG=FALSE (this was in our .env - you might need to look at a config file though.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, especially because of how nice the abort helper is. After looking at the internals of that function, I found this to work.

```
abort( response()->json(['message'=>'Your message'], 401) );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a trait for handling all exception an update your exception/handler.php to call trait instead of showing trace.

Comment: While I appreciate the attempt, this doesn't help my question, doesn't address it, and wouldn't change ANYTHING.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood correctly but it is same as accepted answer but all response can be handled from one place